# Adjusting table row by percentage isnt working

Tags: html

Why the sizes aren't being changed at all? My ideal goal would be to have the first row be 70% and the second be 30%. Any  advice would be greatly appreciated

```
<html>
<body style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px;bottom:0px; right:0px;  margin:0px;">
    <div style='display : table; width : 100%; height : 100%'>
        
        <div style='display : table-row; width : 100%; height : 10%;'>
            <div style="height:100%; width:100%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                blah
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div style='display : table-row; width : 100%; height : 50%;'>
            <div style="height:100%; width:100%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                hah
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a table then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code..

Example link is here:[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aka5w/1/)

**HTML CODE**:

```
<html>
<body style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px;bottom:0px; right:0px;  margin:0px;">
    <div style='display : table; width : 100%; height : 100%'>

        <div style='display : table-row; width : 100%; height : 70%;'>
            <div style="height:70%; width:100%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                blah
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style='display : table-row; width : 100%; height : 30%;'>
            <div style="height:30%; width:100%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                hah
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

hope this code will help for you,Also if you have any clarification,let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

```
<html>
<body style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px;bottom:0px; right:0px;  margin:0px;">
    <div style='display : table; width : 100%; height : 100%'>

        <div style='display : table-row; width : 100%; height : 10%;'>
            <div style="height:100%; width:70%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                blah
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style='display : table-row; width : 100%; height : 50%;'>
            <div style="height:100%; width:30%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                hah
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

or the below one

```
<html>
<body style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px;bottom:0px; right:0px;  margin:0px;">
    <div style='display : table; width : 100%; height : 100%'>

        <div style='display : table-row; width : 70%; height : 10%;'>
            <div style="height:100%; width:100%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                blah
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style='display : table-row; width : 30%; height : 50%;'>
            <div style="height:100%; width:100%; border:solid; display : table-cell;">
                hah
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Happy coding